# Ajax file upload not working on only one server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I made the following script to illustrate the problem. Once the user selects a file, the file gets uploaded to the same script and it returns the filename and filesize it got from `file_get_contents("php://input")`.

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST["upload"])) {
    // received upload - echoing file information
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FILE_NAME"])) {
        $src_file = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $filesize = strlen($src_file);      
        echo "Received via Ajax\n\n";
        echo "Filename: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FILE_NAME"]."\n\n";
        echo "Filesize: ".$filesize;        
    }
} else { ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
        <head>
            <title>Ajax upload test</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
                    <div>
                        <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" class="textbox" /><br />
                    </div>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    //<![CDATA[
                    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
                        $('#fileselect').on('change', function(e) {
                            var files = e.target.files || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
                            for (var i=0, file; file=files[i]; i++) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'ajaxuploadtest.php?upload',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    cache: false,
                                    contentType: false,
                                    processData: false,
                                    data: file,
                                    beforeSend: function(request) {
                                        request.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name', encodeURIComponent(file.name));
                                    },
                                    success: function(file_upload_response) {
                                        alert(file_upload_response);
                                    }
                                });
                            }                   
                        });
                    }
                    //]]>               
                </script>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is it doesn't work on the hosting server where I need to use it. It works on all other hosting servers I've tried (like half a dozen), but on this one server the `success` event never fires if a file has been selected for uploading. It's not reporting any errors.

This is driving me crazy - I don't even know what to tell the hosting company, they have probably changed some server settings but I don't know how to diagnose what's wrong.

Update: Firebug shows that the respons to XHR is 403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /ajaxuploadtest.php on this server. (ajaxuploadtest.php is the file name of the script). Why could that be? And how do I access it in order to send the request from it in the first place?

Comment: Use webdev tools (Chrome/Firebug) to look at what is happening with the request. Also, you didn't implement an onerror callback, so that's why you don't see an error.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are doing this via `php://input`, instead of how a “normal” file upload works? // And don’t output `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` without the necessary escaping, it opens a XSS vulnerability.

Comment: onError doesn't fire either. I have the web developer tools for Firefox but I don't know how to check what's happening with the request. I'll look into it.

Comment: This is part of a really big script I made last year. I'm sure I had a perfectly good reason for using `php://input` but I can't remember why now. And it doesn't matter, works great on a couple of dozen hosting servers so far, I just want to know why it doesn't work on this one server and how to diagnose the problem. Thanks for the tip about `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`. I usually don't do that, but I didn't know it's a XSS vulnerability, I'll check it out.

Comment: Ha, shows 403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access ajaxuploadtest.php (the file name) on this server. What could that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the `mod_security` on the server to which they migrated the site without telling me. Not only did it not allow file uploads, it didn't allow quote, apostrophe and ellipsis characters sent via POST. I had them turn off everything. I really don't understand the reasoning behind such crazy security rules, like you can have text content without apostrophes.